# paypal sandbox notification is not working

Tags: paypal, integration, paypal-sandbox

the notifications of my PayPal sandbox account it was  working, but now the amounts of the accounts are changing but I am not receiving any notifications, I wait 24 hours and nothing

I check the woocomerce log and everything looks fine, any idea what can be happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "notifications" ? Provide a sample of something that was working.

IPN history for a sandbox account can be reviewed at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history , and any delivery failures will be explained there.

Email and SMS messages for sandbox accounts associated with a developer account will appear in its dashboard Notifications tab, https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/

Comment: Thank you for your response, I mean the notifications of the developer account to review the invoice that paypal will send in the live staging .